# How to make this button not disrupt surroundings

Tags: html, css

I have this code for a cute little button

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
button {
color: white;
font: 18px verdana;
background-color: #6fcafc;
border-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #60b3e0;
border-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 7px;
border-radius: 12px;
padding: 5px;
}
button:active {
border-bottom-width: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 7px;
}
button:focus {
outline: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click Me!</button>
<br>
Text that might be here.
</body>
</html>
```

It moves up and down when I push it. But, because of how it works with moving the button down a bit and removing the border, when I click it, the text below moves up. Could someone please explain to me how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `margin-bottom` to the button, to offset the `top` value.

```css
button {
  color: white;
  font: 18px verdana;
  background-color: #6fcafc;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #60b3e0;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 7px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

button:active {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  top: 7px;
  /* added */
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me!</button>
<br> Text that might be here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same amount of border-bottom-width when the button is active

```css
button {
color: white;
font: 18px verdana;
background-color: #6fcafc;
border-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #60b3e0;
border-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 7px;
border-radius: 12px;
padding: 5px;
}
button:active {
border-bottom-width: 7px;
position: relative;
top: 7px;
}
button:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<button>Click Me!</button>
<br>
Text that might be here.
</body>
```